# How to identify the MAC address of primary physical lan card?

Tags: c#, mac-address

I am developing window application in C#. I am using the following code to obtain the MAC address

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "Hi";

            string macAddresses = "";

            foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            lbl1.Text = macAddresses;

        }
```

In the above code I am not getting the MAC address of the primary lan card. In my computer I created two loopback adapters A & B. I have one physical Lan Card. Now I want to obtain the MAC address of the primary physical Lan Card instead of A & B. How to do this ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Change the condition to:

```
 // instead of nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
 nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
```

Or use this:

```
    nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet || nic.NetworkInterfaceType  ==  etworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetFx || nic.NetworkInterfaceType ==              NetworkInterfaceType.FastEthernetT
```

Comment: What is not working, can you be more specific?? What do you get? Do you get an exception??

Comment: In both the cases I am getting the the MAC address of the Loopback Adapter named as 'Network B'. I have one 'Real Lan Card' which is my actual Lan Card. I want the MAC Address of 'Real Lan Card'

Comment: Review your code my friend. There is got to be something else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use this link if you use localhost as the target IP address...
[How to get the Mac address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142088/how-to-get-the-mac-address-prior-to-connection)