# Is there a built-in way to check if an IP address is already occupied?

Tags: c#, ip

My software changes the IP of a computer, but I am coming into conflicts with other devices.  Is there a built-in way to check if an IP address is already occupied/taken before setting it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean other devices (NICs) of the same machine, or devices on other machines in the same subnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your network doesn't use DHCP and IP addresses really do need to be manually assigned, you could try using the [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) to see if a host on the network responds.

Comment: Assuming the host responds to pings.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  This looks great, thanks. +1 and accept.

Comment: @user664939 Glad I could help; @Phil Thanks for your valuable answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class, as Donut suggested, but not all devices will respond to Pings. However, any device with an IP address will respond to [ARP](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/ARP.html) requests if they are communicating with the network properly.

If you can find a way to send out an ARP request that says "Who has IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?" and you get a response, then you know someone else has that IP address. I personally don't know how to do that off the top of my head, but you could try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1148778/138757) for information on how to access ARP information.

Also, [this](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.sendarp) might be a useful resource.

Comment: I think that the ping class should suffice (the other machines on the network should respond), but this looks like a more in-depth alternative if I need it. Thanks and +1.

Comment: A ping would suffice for most situations, I just offered an answer for completeness (and because I was curious myself).