# How to Get all Ip address in the Lan using Windows Store Apps(C# and Xaml)

Tags: network-programming, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently working on Windows Store Application, I am trying in all the way to get the list of IP addresses of the machines which are connected in LAN, but I am unable to get since I could find the Network Interface class but in that GetAllNetworkInterfaces() is not present in the .net for Windows Store Apps framework, Please any one guide me on any other way for getting the Ip addresses that are connected in LAN for Windows Store Apps.
GetAllNetworkInterfaces() method sample in the following link

http://www.mindstick.com/Blog/149/Retriving%20network%20device%20information%20in%20center code here

If you can provide me with any useful links related to this that would be most helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The network information in WSA is available in `Windows.Networking.Connectivity`.

[+info](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/accessing-network-profile-information-in-windows-store-apps/)

[++info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207308.aspx)

After knowing the available interfaces, and IP of the LAN adapter you should try sending ICMP's (to fill ARP table) or RARP's directly [+info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148778/how-do-i-access-arp-protocol-information-through-net)  and I don't know if ARP table or the interface for sending RARP's is accesible from WSA. Good luck!