# Simple way to get MAC (Physical) address from inputted IP?

Tags: c#, ip, host, mac-address

Is there any command similar to this code to print out the MAC address or "hash code" of the IP stored in this variable? I have done some research and it looks like it can be a really complex to impossible task. But I think it is worth a shot to ask. (Edit: Any IP I search is an internal IP to my Network).

```
            IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(inputIP); //uses the input IP data into the addr variable to get host
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr); //Get hostname
            Console.WriteLine("IP Address: " + addr);
            Console.WriteLine("Host Name: " + entry.HostName); //output logic
```

Comment: You can't magically translate IP address to MAC address. For a local IP address you can query the ARP table but I'm not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the MAC address of an ip which is not on your local network (i.e. the internet). For local IP/MAC addresses you can do an `arp` lookup.

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148778/how-do-i-access-arp-protocol-information-through-net) explains the arp lookup.

Comment: I forgot to add that they are all internal IP's, sorry about that. Thanks for the link, I will take a look at that.